# SQL Fix Name Column by Separating Capitals

Tags: sql, case

We had a technical support agent mess up and accidentally strip the space between the first middle and last name in our "FullName" column.

So instead of

```
John Alan Smith
```

the names read

```
JohnAlanSmith
```

We do not have the names in individual columns, nor do we have another source of the names.  This is for a third party application.

We have 1500+ users in the database, so we need to easily correct the issue.  The only method I can think of is by detecting capitals.  Of course, we would need to somehow exclude capitals in the middle of the last name like McDonald, etc.

Can we issue a SQL statement to do this?  Even if we only had to correct 100 names manually it would be better than 1500+.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Test each answer with a name like JimBobMacDonald.  You might want to look for an query on names with only two capital letters and do the rest manually.

Comment: @sgeddes - I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition

Comment: Brady -- the solution I posted with the Fiddle should work in 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't resist trying this.  The following code is for SQL Server, and it actually does work (you can check out on sqlfiddle).

This is a multi-step process.  The idea is to identify the location of each capital letter in the name, by joining to a bunch of numbers and checking the value of the character to see if it is capitalized.  Each capital letter is on its own row.

Then, extract the name portion for that and concatenate the strings together for each string.  This method works, assuming the first letter is capitalized (which is easily fixed if this is not the case).

Also, remember some capitals are not "edges":  "McGarvey", "Chen-Smith" and so on.

Each of these steps is going to vary by database.

```
with somenums as (
      select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5
     ),
     nums as (
      select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select NULL)) as n
      from somenums s cross join somenums s2
     ),
     test as (
         select 'JohnAlanSmith' as name union all
         select 'MaryElizabethChou'
     ),
     caps as (
      select name, n
      from test join
           nums
           on ascii(SUBSTRING(test.name, nums.n, 1)) between ascii('A') and ascii('Z')
    ),
    nameparts as (
     select name, n, nextn, SUBSTRING(name, n, coalesce(nextn - n, 1000)) as namepart
     from (select name, n,
                  (select min(n) from caps c2 where c2.name = c.name and c2.n > c.n
                  ) as nextn
           from caps c
          ) c
    )
select name,
       STUFF((select ' '+namepart
              from nameparts np2
              where np2.name = np.name
              order by n
              for xml path ('')
             ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as betterName
from nameparts np
group by name
```

Comment: This looks great, but I couldn't get it to work in sqlfiddle.  Can you provide an example table?  Thanks!

Comment: @Brady . . . The sample table is the CTE called `test`.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL:

When you don't want to waste much time writing a complicated function, you might have a try with something like this:

```
/*test data*/
create table foo(name varchar(50));
insert into foo values ('JohnAndySmith');

select
name,
trim(replace(replace(name, 'A', ' A'), 'S', ' S'))
from
foo
```

See it live [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3084b/3/0).

Of course you'd have to do it for the whole alphabet. The `TRIM()` function removes a space in front of the first letter.

For more info on the functions I used see the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html).

Comment: @DanBracuk . . . The same as all the other solutions.  It will split it into two names.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your RDBMS, something like this could work.  This is specifically for SQL Serer and uses a function that accepts a field and a position in the string and returns the string up until the next capital letter:

```
select field, fname, mname, dbo.ReturnCapString(field,len(fname)+len(mname)+1) lname
from
  (
    select field, fname, dbo.ReturnCapString(field,len(fname)+1) mname
    from
      (
      select field, dbo.ReturnCapString(field,1) fname
      from yourtable
        ) t
    ) t2
```

And the function -- the main thing about the function is the `ASCII` check to see if the character is capital or not:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ReturnCapString (@String VARCHAR(100), @Pos int) 
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS 
BEGIN 
   DECLARE @return varchar(100) 
   DECLARE @position INT 
   DECLARE @counter INT 

   SET @position = @Pos + 1
   SET @counter = 1
   SET @return = ''

   WHILE @position <= DATALENGTH(@string) AND @return = ''
   BEGIN 
       IF ASCII(SUBSTRING(@string, @position, 1)) BETWEEN 65 AND 90  
           SELECT @return = SUBSTRING(@string, @pos, @counter)

       SET @position = @position + 1 
       SET @counter = @counter + 1 

   END 

   IF @return = '' 
   BEGIN
     SET @return = SUBSTRING(@String, @Pos, LEN(@string))
   END 

   RETURN @return 
END
```

And of course, the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7dd49/1) to demonstrate.

BTW -- thanks for the interesting question!  And while this isn't perfect (don't think anything will be 100% perfect) use this fiddle if you need to potentially flag any obvious issues: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77f446/10

```
FLAG   FIELD            FNAME    MNAME    LNAME
       JohnAlanSmith    John     Alan     Smith
       McDonalds        Mc                Donalds
X      JimBobMacDonald  Jim      Bob      Mac
```